# Is it bad to move my laptop (or change its orientation) while its on if it has a Solid State Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

I am thinking of putting a solid state hard drive in my computer. Besides from the obvious major beneficial factor of upgraded read/write speeds i also have this habit of  ALWAYS turning off my laptop before i put it in my backpack and go to/from school and also class to class.

I do this because i know the hard drive is a spinning disk with some angular momentum and any rotation of the orientation of my laptop would cause the hard drive to force a change in its angular momentum causing force on it. As a result i avoid any shift in my laptops orientation while its on to avoid damage to the hard drive.

I was wondering if solid state drives completely get rid of this issue (obviously there is no moving component so there is no mechanical force) or if there is still are reason (besides battery life which is retained pretty well in sleep mode) that i should not move my laptop with a solid state drive in it. What if it has a dual SSD and HDD in it (one for booting and large programs and the other for data storage)?

Comment: In sleep mode you have nothing to fear about moving an HDD, because it's asleep (not powered on, no rotation). So there's no issue in the first place?

Comment: I did not know this...

Comment: Most laptops have sensors that prevent what you describe with mechanical drives.  **SSDs have no mechanical parts.**  So even if what you describe was an actual issue SSDs couldn't have this issue for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

A solid state drive has no moving parts, so moving your laptop while the drive is being access will have a negligible affect on how it works. If you have an optical disc in a drive, you might want to eject that first though.

Most laptops by default put themselves into sleep mode if they are closed. You can also put the computer into sleep mode manually. When in this state, all drive reads and writes stop so it is safe to move it around without any chance of damaging the drive.

Answer (score 2):

I would compare your laptop with a solid state drive to your mobile phone - with practically no moving parts or to a tablet. Except for the fact the construct of a mobile phone / tablet are different from the laptop - they are no different. (Just recall the number of times users toss or rotate their phones when they hold them)

On a side note: As @Techie007 pointed out, once to put your laptop into sleep mode - practically most moving parts lay motionless inside the laptop and can cause no harm because of their orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop Manufacturers design Laptops to tolerate/withstand subtle movements like changing the orientation of the Latop (in case of putting it in your bag). 
I'd advice to keep your Laptop in a Laptop Bag with sufficient padding as it will cushion any sudden jerks. Other than that you should be fine